# How to get user contact information into MongoDB using Express, MongoDB, and Node.js?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, express

I know that I am very close to being able to get user data into MongoDb using express and node.js. The following is the code I have. When I fill out the form and click submit, I am still not able to get the user information into the mongoDB database. What steps am I missing so that when the user clicks submit on the contact form, I am able to have access to the user information on the back-end through MongoDB?

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <body>

<form action="/api/forms">
  First name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="firstname" value="First Name">
  <br>
  Last name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="Last Name">
  <br><br>
   E-mail:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lastname" value="E-mail">

  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 


</body>
</html>
```

The following is my Express and Node.js code. I  have made a post request just like on the HTML contact form. But it seems I am still missing a step to get actual user information from the contact form into MongoDB.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');







app.post('/api/forms', function(req,res){
  res.send('Please use /api/forms');

});

app.get('/api/forms', function(req,res){
  Forms.getForms(function(err,forms){
      if(err){
        throw err;
      }

      res.json(forms);
    });
});
```

Comment: Markup is wrong, and your server snippet looks so incomplete that I'm wondering how it even gets executed.

Comment: Err, where are you getting `Forms` from?

Comment: Not to sound pompous, but you do realize I am asking this very question, because I do not know how to get the app.post to post my form into a database. Where am I getting Forms from? It is from the address in the HTML form. It is a clue for you to use in helping me make that function parameter into a reality. Now if you do not know how to answer the question, then say so. I will keep looking elsewhere if need be.